# Android/Java - setText to button within onbuttonclick cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, button, settext

First let me preface this with being completely new to Android development.  I am trying to simply have text on a different buttons change when I click on "this" button.  I can change the visibility fine with setVisibility() so I think I am referencing the buttons correctly - but when I attempt to setText() I get the error:  "Cannot resolve method 'setText(Java.Lang.String)'"

Why will it allow me to change visibility but not text?  What do I need to do to correct the problem?

Here's a portion of the XML for one of the buttons I am attempting to change text on:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/songbutton4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Here is the code for the onclick event:

```
public void onbutton1click(View v){
 //on click turn the 4 buttons invisible, and show the other 5
    View b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View b3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View b4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View b5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    View sb1 = findViewById(R.id.songbutton1);
    sb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sb1.setText("hello");  // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    View sb2 = findViewById(R.id.songbutton2);
    sb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    View sb3 = findViewById(R.id.songbutton3);
    sb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    View sb4 = findViewById(R.id.songbutton4);
    sb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing it in Fragment or in Activity?

Anyway, you should do:

```
Button sb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.songbutton1);
```

This is how we add elements. If you set Button widget in your layout, in this way you need to have reference to this widget. Declaring proper type and casting using ( ).

If you are doing it in Fragment, not in Activity, you also need to bind it to proper view.

```
Button sb1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.songbutton1);
```

And advice - don't get reference to views (widgets) in listener. Do it before listener.

Comment: Perfect solution.  I tried swapping out the bad "view" code I was using with the correct code you posted, and it obviously worked fine.  Thank you for the answer, and the advice about referencing the widgets before the listener.  I will keep that in mind.  [And yes, this was in an Activity]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly assign the button to a variable i.e: `Button btnSong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.songbutton4);` 
then set an onclick listener to the button through the method `btSong.setOnClickListener();` which will require you to declare a new onClickListener inside the button and a method will be created within which u can place the above code under the method. Alternatively add an XML attribute that points the button straight to the method.